# Не обновляется state

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Есть вот такой код.

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState({
    tableField:'',searchText:'',searchСondition:''
})
const onChangeHandler = (e:any)=> {
    setSearchText({...searchText, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    console.log("LOOK THIS", searchText)
    
}
return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">

                <div className='col-md-3 mainSearcher'>
                    <select 
                    className = "selected"  
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                    name="tableField"
                    >
                        <option>Дата</option>
                        <option>Название</option>
                        <option>Количество</option>
                        <option>Расстояние</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3 mainSearcher">
                    <input 
                        type='text'
                        name='searchText'
                        onChange={onChangeHandler}
                        className = "searched"
                        placeholder='Поиск'
                    >
                    </input>
                </div>
                <div className='col-md-3 mainSearcher'>
                    <select className="selected"  
                    onChange={onChangeHandler} 
                    name="searchСondition">
                        <option>Равно</option>
                        <option>Больше</option>
                        <option>Меньше</option>
                        <option>Содержит</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

)

Проблема в том, что после ввода или выбора из поля в стейт ничего не добавляется. Добавление происходит при следующем действие, но добавляются старые данные.

Comment: используйте [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en), чтобы смотреть текущее состояние. `setState` - асинхронная функция и срабатывает после `console.log`, поэтому вы видите в консоле предыдущее состояние, а не актуальное.

Comment: а как мне дождаться выполнения setState, чтобы продолжить выполнения handlera. Мне нужно просто сделать фильтрацию данных от параметров в стейте.

Comment: фильтровать данные до записи в стейт.

Comment: Не совсем понял. У меня есть 3 параметра, которые хранятся в state, и зависимости от которых, я фильтрую данные. я не могу сделать это до